# Django unit test IntegrityError handling

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I have a `TransactionManagementError` in my Django unittest attemption.
Here is my model:

```
class Like(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'post'])]
```

Here is my testing view:

```
class LikeCreateDestroyAPIView(APIView):
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        like = Like.objects.create(user=self.request.user, post=Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['post_id']))
        reply = 'like created'
        status = 201
    except IntegrityError:
        like_to_delete = Like.objects.get(user=self.request.user, post=Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['post_id']))
        like = copy.deepcopy(like_to_delete)
        like_to_delete.delete()
        reply = 'like deleted'
        status = 204
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({'status': "Post doesn't exist"}, status=404)

    return Response({reply: model_to_dict(like)}, status=status)
```

Here is my unit test inherits from `rest_framework.test.APITestCase`.
I try to get like by already liked user (successfully added like with that user before test) so it violates integrity constraint of the Like model.

```
   # Authorized by liked user
    response3 = self.client.get(
        reverse("like-create-api", args=[self.test_post_11.id]),
        HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=f"JWT {self.access_token_user1}"
    )

    self.assertEqual(response3.status_code, 204)
```

Can somebody help with any advise?

Answer (score 0):

So I just changed LikeCreateDestroyAPIView to avoid IntegrityError. So now the test is passed. But anyway it's interesting why the test violates the error and how to solve such an exception in testing?